# NullPointer on LayoutInflater - Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I have a class in another java file that I'm calling in my MainActivity. I need to inflate some layouts in the external class. The problem I'm having is specifying the context, because when I try to inflate the layouts I get a Null Pointer Exception. The class doesn't have it's own `onCreate()` method so I need to pass the context from my MainActivity? Not sure how to go about it. This is causing me the `NullPointerException`:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);;
```

`NullPointerException` on `Context` context:

```
public class CameraListener extends Activity implements OnCameraChangeListener {

    private static final int SCALE_HEIGHT = 50;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleC3iActivity mParent;


    Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: If the answer does not work, paste the entire class (without the methods, just the relevant parts of code)

Comment: Use `LayoutInflater.from(context)`.

Comment: The NPE is before the LayoutInflater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple Issues

**First**

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

You shouldn't need the getApplicationContext(), since you already have it.

OR *(credits : @Delyan)*

```
LayoutInflater.from(context)
```

**Second**

`Context context = getApplicationContext();` does not work before `setContentView`. So you need to initialize context after you call `setContentView` in your `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    context = getApplicationContext() ;
```

Same goes for `LayoutInflater`, you need to initialize it in the `onCreate`

Comment: Better yet, `LayoutInflater.from(context)`.

Comment: Ok, except I get the NPE on `Context context = getApplicationContext();`

Comment: paste the entire class (without useless methods), with method where u are calling this\

Comment: There is no onCreate in this class. It's not an Activity.

Comment: If you `extends Activity` you have no choice dude. What are you thinking ? This is the first basics of Android programming, and dont assume pure Java rules here. Android has some basic construct expectations.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` extends from `Context` that means you just need `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);` in your `onCreate()` method.