# Adding a footer to a listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView populated with dummy "locations." This works fine. Now, I am trying to add a footer to the bottom of the ListView (a progess bar). When I do this, I get a null pointer error and I'm not sure why. Any ideas? Thanks!

The error happens on this line

`listView.addFooterView(footerView);`

Here is the logcat:

```
06-05 00:43:27.887: D/AndroidRuntime(1839): Shutting down VM
06-05 00:43:27.887: W/dalvikvm(1839): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419397c0)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test6/com.example.test6.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at com.example.test6.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 00:43:27.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
```

and the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<Location> arrayOfLocations;
LocationAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arrayOfLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.progress_footer, null, false);
        listView.addFooterView(footerView);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    adapter = new LocationAdapter(this, arrayOfLocations);

            // fill list from webserver by using AsyncTask
    FillLocations myList2 = new FillLocations();
    myList2.execute();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (listView != null
                    && listView.getAdapter() != null
                    && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1) != null
                    && listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView
                            .getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                    && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1)
                            .getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {

                startLoop += 10;
                endLoop += 10;

            }
        }

    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way i guess your `context` is `NULL` so you got `NPE`

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
        R.layout.progress_footer, null, false);`
```

### Update:

add your

`listView.addFooterView(footerView);`

after

`listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);`

Comment: This works when I have a set amount of listings in the list. I tried implementing it after populating the list using AsyncTask to get from a webserver and then I got another error but this time on `listView.addFooterView(footerView)` I have updated the main post to show this. Thanks

Comment: @user1282637 add your `listView.addFooterView(footerView);` after  `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);`

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't display at all (no error, though)

Comment: Scratch that. It works. I can't believe I missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem with `null context`. You have to initialize your context. [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429205/nullpointer-on-layoutinflater-android)  it.

**Second Issue**

Here you have to initialize `listView` before addFooterView. Your code sequence should be

First initialize

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

then

```
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I solved that part and have updated by code to what happens when I change to MinActivity.this

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace this code:
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.progress_footer, null, false);
With this code:
View footerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.progress_footer, null, false);
```

Comment: This works when I have a set amount of listings in the list. I tried implementing it after populating the list using AsyncTask to get from a webserver and then I got another error but this time on `listView.addFooterView(footerView)`

Comment: I have updated the main post to show my new problem. Thank you if you help

Comment: you always have add footer or header after initialize list object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
        R.layout.progress_footer, null, false);
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Replace your `context` with `MainActivity.this`. Using Context directly sometimes could be null and hence would cause **nullpointerexception**. Using `ClassName.this` instead of context will provide a more explicit context value which possibly could not be null.